# Grunt bounces my terminal dock icon on OSX

Tags: macos, gruntjs

I'm just starting to use Grunt on OSX. I initialise a folder watch with `grunt watch`. Every time I make a change and Grunt runs, the dock icon for terminal bounces and a red "1" indicator bubble appears. This is very annoying. Has anybody found a way around this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like grunt is appending the terminal bell character (\x07) to fail messages, see here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/25728e1744836b42927962a005fe1ce15f55640f/lib/grunt/fail.js#L31

Reading the code, it looks like you can disable this terminal bell by specifying the 'color' grunt option (which doesn't make sense to me). You can stick this in the top of your gruntfile:

```
grunt.option('color', false);
```

(I would love to know if there is a more elegant way of specifying grunt options.)

Answer (score 0):

I have just successfully suppressed this EXTREMELY annoying behaviour with the following:

1: Open Terminal (given if you're reading this you came here as a result of a bouncing Terminal icon I shouldn't have to point out that it's in Applications->Utilities->Terminal

2: Type the following:

```
$ defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE
$ kilall Dock
```

3: Thank the folks over at Switching to Mac who [pointed this out](http://www.switchingtomac.com/tutorials/how-to-permanently-stop-dock-icons-from-bouncing/).

Comment: To clarify- this kills the bounce for all apps, permanently-- not just stupid grunt.